# PHP, Mysql Calendar

Tags: php

I have created a calendar which is connected to mysql. The calendar searchs mysql and shows the number of employees on timeoff. There are several managers for a variety of employees. I created a searchterm box at which the manager can type there name and the code will query the database specific to the managers name (essentially only showing that managers employees instead of the whole company). The number of employess on time off are shown inside the calendar as a link and the total number for that specific day. Once clicked it then shows the employee names associated with the day.  The problem im having is once the manager clicks onto the link, it automatically defaults to all employees instead of the ones specific to the manager. The managers search term is getting dropped and the code is defaulting back as if nothing was entered. My question is how I can reuse that searchterm over and over again until other wise directed.

```
$searchTerm = trim($_GET['keyname']);


if( $searchTerm != 'All Drivers' && $searchTerm != '')

{
$sqlEvent2 = mysql_query("select * FROM timeoff_365_days where (DM = '$searchTerm' or FM = '$searchTerm' or region ='$searchTerm' or location ='$searchTerm') and  TimeOffDate = '".$year."-".$month."-".$i."'"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sqlEvent2);

echo '<div id="button">';
echo "<a  href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$i."&year=".$year. "&v=false  ' >".$num_rows."</a></td>"; 
echo '</div>';


}
else{






 $sqlEvent = mysql_query( "select * FROM timeoff_365_days where TimeOffDate = '".$year."-".$month."-".$i."'"  );
if (!$sqlEvent) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}



$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sqlEvent);
echo '<div id="button">';
echo "<a  href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$i."&year=".$year."&v=true' >".$num_rows."</a></td>"; 
echo '</div>'; 

 $sqlEvent = mysql_query( "select * FROM timeoff_365_days where TimeOffDate = '".$year."-".$month."-".$i."'"  );
if (!$sqlEvent) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}



$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sqlEvent);
echo '<div id="button">';
echo "<a  href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$i."&year=".$year."&v=true' >".$num_rows."</a></td>"; 
echo '</div>'; 

}

} 

echo "<tr>";
echo"</table>";
?>
<div class="accordion vertical">
<ul>
<li> 
<input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio-accordion" />
            <label for="radio-3">Time Off by Driver Code</label>
            <div class="content">




<?php
if(($_GET['v']==false)) {
$sqlEvent2 = "select * FROM timeoff_365_days where (DM = '$searchTerm' or FM = '$searchTerm' or region ='$searchTerm'or location ='$searchTerm') and TimeOffDate ='".$year."/".$month."/".$day."'";
$resultEvents2 = mysql_query($sqlEvent2);

while ($events2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents2)){
echo $events2['DriverCode']."-";
echo $events2['Unit']."</br>";
}
}
else {
echo "";

}
?>

<?php
echo "<tr >";
var_dump($searchTerm);


if(isset($_GET['v'])) {
$sqlEvent = "select * FROM timeoff_365_days where TimeOffDate ='".$year."/".$month."/".$day."'";
$resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);

while ($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
echo $events['DriverCode']."-";
echo $events['Unit']."</br>";
}
}
else {
echo "";
}
echo "<tr>"; 

var_dump($searchTerm);

?>
```

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET it with $_GET, so do it in the url with domain.com/index.php?search=asddf

Comment: My search bar is on the same page as the calendar. Im eventually going to be formatting it into a menu bit for now just trying to get it to search through text. Everytime I put the name in the search, page reloads and loses the searchterm. The same thing happens when i click on a link. Is there anyway to make the code refer to the searchterm everytime it reloads?

Comment: If you submit the form you got the searchquery so use this with $_POST in the link